What is the benefit of providing an app signing key to Firebase for messaging?
Firebase Console provides the option to add a signing key in the firebase project settings, see screenshot:

However, this doesn't seem to influence push notifications (on android):

correct signing key -> push is received
wrong signing key   -> push is received
no signing key      -> push is received

So what are the benefits of providing a signing key? Do i need it only for other firebase services?

As your test probably confirms, it's indeed only required for certain services. And it's not only the hash of the signing-key, but in combination with the package-name. So the purpose is to make sure it's the right package-name with one of the right signatures.
